# How can I create a row of scalable square elements with Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create a 6 bootstrap 5 cards to act as buttons, all are col-xl-2 wide that need to be exactly square in height.

[image]

I am creating the card with the following. Can anyone help point me in the right direction to make this work?

```css
.card-buttons:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
  align-self: center!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Fo3rlrZj/k7ujTnHg4CGR2D7kSs0v4LLanw2qksYuRlEzO+tcaEPQogQ0KaoGN26/zrn20ImR1DfuLWnOo7aBA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row mt-4 ">
    <div class="col-2 mx-auto">
      <div class="card card-body card-buttons">
        <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-2 mx-auto">
      <div class="card card-body card-buttons">
        <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-2 mx-auto">
      <div class="card card-body card-buttons">
        <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-2 mx-auto">
      <div class="card card-body card-buttons">
        <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-2 mx-auto">
      <div class="card card-body card-buttons">
        <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-2 mx-auto">
      <div class="card card-body card-buttons">
        <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not add a fixed `height: 100px` or something instead of what you're doing?

Comment: I need the height to scale with the width as the page is responsive.

Answer (score 0):

We can accomplish this by making the cards themselves flex rows (inside a flex row) so that the pseudo-elements which set our height don't stack vertically on other child elements.

```css
.card:before {
  content: '';
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Fo3rlrZj/k7ujTnHg4CGR2D7kSs0v4LLanw2qksYuRlEzO+tcaEPQogQ0KaoGN26/zrn20ImR1DfuLWnOo7aBA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row d-flex mt-4">
    <div class="col-2">
      <div class="card card-body card-buttons flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <div class="card card-body card-buttons flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <div class="card card-body card-buttons flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <div class="card card-body card-buttons flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <div class="card card-body card-buttons flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <div class="card card-body card-buttons flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```